# etags and other tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The [etags](/questions/tagged/etags) tag is a synonym of [etag](/questions/tagged/etag), and has the description

> A program to generate tags for a large project. These tags are usable by the Emacs text editor.

This is inconsistent: tags in that sense are always plural, i.e. `etags`, never `etag`. [etag](/questions/tagged/etag) evidently refers to another concept, [HTTP Etag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Should [etags](/questions/tagged/etags) remain a synonym of [etag](/questions/tagged/etag), and be about HTTP Etags, and should Emacs `etags` be tagged [ctags](/questions/tagged/ctags)+[emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs)? Or should the synonym be unmade, with HTTP Etags on [etag](/questions/tagged/etag) and `etags` on [etags](/questions/tagged/etags)?

Comment: 25 questions in `etag` are also tagged with `http`, 30 with `caching`, 11 with `http-headers`, 8 with `apache`, etc.  **It's clear that the vast majority of questions in the `etag` tag are *not* about the Emacs/ctags feature, but about the HTTP ETag header**.  Either the Emacs/ctags feature needs to find a better tag name, or all of the questions -- the *majority* in the tag -- need to be moved over to `http-etag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also [http-etag](/questions/tagged/http-etag) for the Http Etags...although it only has 2 questions, it does seem like the best option for this meaning of the tag